# HTML form table acting stubborn

Tags: html, forms, html-table

I've tried to style the input, td, tr, table, div and every other option available. These are all suggestions found on Google so don't blame me.

I am struggling to fixing this  table, but it just doesn't want to look like how I want it to look.

I've used `<td style="width:100%";>, <td style="width:100px";>, <td width="100%">, <td width="100px">` and go on....

The first picture is how it looks, second is how I need and want it to look:

[image: frustration]

Here is the code (no award for looking good):

```
<div class="mail" style="width:600px">
<form onSubmit="return checkrequired(this)" action="includes/mail.php" method="POST">
<table border="0" style="width:100%">
<tr><td><strong>First name: </strong></td><td><input tabindex="1" type="text" name="requiredfirstname" maxlength="30"/></td><td> *</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Last name: </strong></td><td><input tabindex="2" type="text" name="requiredlastname" maxlength="30"/></td><td> *</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Shipping address: </strong></td><td><input tabindex="3" type="text" name="requiredshippingaddress" maxlength="30"/></td><td> *</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Shipping address 2: </strong></td><td><input tabindex="4" type="text" name="shippingaddress_2" maxlength="30"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>City: </strong></td><td><input type="text" name="requiredcity" value="<?= $town ?>" maxlength="30"/><br /></td><td> *</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>State: </strong></td><td><select name="state">
  <option value="<?= $state ?>"><?= $state ?></option>
  <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
  <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
  <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="California">California</option>
  <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
  <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
  <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
  <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
  <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
  <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
  <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
  <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
  <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
  <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
  <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
  <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
  <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
  <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
  <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
  <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
  <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
  <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
  <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
  <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
  <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
  <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
  <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
  <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
  <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
  <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
  <option value="New York">New York</option>
  <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
  <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
  <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
  <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
  <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
  <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
  <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
  <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
  <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
  <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
  <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
  <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
  <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
  <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
  <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
  <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
  <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Country: </strong></td><td> 
<select name="country">
  <option value="<?= $country ?>"><?= $country ?></option>
  <option value="US">United States</option>
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Postal code: </strong></td><td><input type="text" name="requiredpostalcode" value="<?= $record->postal_code; ?>" maxlength="9"/></td><td> *</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Phone number: </strong></td><td><input type="text" name="areacode" value="<?= $record->area_code; ?>" maxlength="3"/>
<input tabindex="5" type="text" name="phonedigit3" maxlength="3"/>
<input tabindex="6" type="text" name="phonedigit4" maxlength="4"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>E-mail: </strong></td><td><input tabindex="7" type="text" name="requiredemail" maxlength="30"/></td><td> *</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Message: </strong></td><td><textarea tabindex="8 "name="message" maxlength="250"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td><input tabindex="9" type="submit" value="Send"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Firstly your tr's td counts are not equal. You should use colspan property. [check out this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)

Comment: Lastly, find yourself a tutorial on how to create forms. You don't use a `<table>` to create a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how well it would work in other browsers, but this looks fine in chrome:

```
<tr>
<td><strong>Phone number: </strong></td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="areacode" value="<?= $record->area_code; ?>" maxlength="3" style="width:30px;"/>
<input tabindex="5" type="text" name="phonedigit3" maxlength="3" style="width:30px;"/>
<input tabindex="6" type="text" name="phonedigit4" maxlength="4" style="width:75px;" />
</td>
</tr>
```

Note for this to look consistent across different browsers you'd probably need to explicitly set the width on all the inputs, something like this in your css:

```
input[type="text"], select {
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: This looks promising thank you very much for helping. I tried this exact same thing but it didn't output good on my browser. But I copy/pasted your code into jfiddle and works great.

Comment: @F4LLCON Apparently you didn't see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GJzKc/) that I included in my comment. You either style it inline or create a class to apply to those input fields.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Your DEMO isn't correct because the spacing between the words and fields and * are like the distance from the moon to the earth

Comment: It's not my fault that you don't know how to use a table (`style="width:100%"`). Learn the basics of HTML. Once you do, you will stop using tables for forms.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO it was meant in conjunction with the element styles on the phone number inputs from the first half of my answer, in an attempt to achieve consistency across browsers/platforms. http://jsfiddle.net/mnahkies/SFznk/

Comment: @Michael We both know that a table is not the way to create a form.

Answer (score 0):

Do not style TD elements, style actual controls (Input, Select etc.)

Comment: Could you please JFiddle your code where input etc. are styled? Then we can see what is working and what is not for real?

Answer (score 0):

The `style` property has to be applied to the `input`; not the table cell.

```
<input style="width: ...
```

Comment: Well go read on google, everywhere they say it has to be in the <td> like how I posted it. I've tried in the input still doesn't work. You think I will post this question without testing it first?

Comment: Considering the terrible quality of questions on here, I assume no one knows anything. Apparently you're searching the wrong thing on Google. You don't apply it to the table cell unless **each** input field has its own cell. Even if it did, the input fields would overflow. The property must be applied to the input. [See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/GJzKc/)

Comment: Considering not everyone has studied asking questions on here, people must help with the problem and not saying that the question quality isn't A+ approved..

Comment: Apparently you wouldn't have posted the question without testing it first.

Comment: look mister 'perfect' go buzz somewhere else. And I tested it before posting, it didn't work. Looks like you are also stubborn like the code

Comment: Code isn't stubborn. It's the programmer who writes the code.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, from the source above, the table has "100 %" width, which means, all available horizontal space.

The TD's don't have any width presettings, so the distribute "evenly", 1/3rd or 33% each.

This is possible, since the inner elements (input and text noddes) as well do not have any width presetting.

You might give the TDs a width, but that would not alter anything on the input's, they stay on their "default" of around 30 chars.

Easiest way to achieve what you want:

1.) leave the table as is.
2.) set the width of the input fields and the '*' textnode explicitly on what you want

```
#firstname {
width: 135px;
}


 <tr><td><strong>First name: </strong></td><td><input tabindex="1" type="text" 
name="requiredfirstname" id="firstname" maxlength="30"/></td><td> *</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You avoid the problem by using a single `<input type=tel>` field for the phone number. Dividing it into three fields is bad for usability (e.g., the user cannot conveniently cut and paste his phone number).

If you keep using three fields for the phone number, you need to set the widths of those fields so that their combined width, plus any spacing between them, equals the width of fields in other cells of the same column. This is possible, but cumbersome, and would make the layout even more rigid (with pixel widths).